# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket using opcua.client.py connect to opc ua server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, opc-ua

Hello I try to connect OPCUA server using opcua client.

I have used simatic opcua server.

I write a code using python

```
from opcua import Client
```

import pandas as pd
import threading

__all_ = ['communication']

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\OPCUA\Working_VF1_5.xls', sheet_name='Tag List')

class Communication:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.is_connected = False
    self.plc = ""
    self.mylock = threading.Lock()


# Connection method
def opc_client_connect(self):
    try:
        # #  Read connection string for url
        url = read_clienturl()
        self.client = Client("opc.tcp://WAP120153:55101")


        # self.client.find_servers(uris='opc.tcp://WAP120153:55101/')
        print(self.client)
        self.client.connect()
        is_connected = True
        root = self.client.get_root_node()
        print(root)
        objects = root.get_child('Objects')
        symbols = objects.get_child('1:SYM:')
        stnname,plcname = get_station_plc_name()
        stnametostring = '7:' + stnname
        plcnametostring = '7:' + plcname
        station_name = symbols.get_child(stnametostring)
        self.plc = station_name.get_child(plcnametostring)



    except Exception as e:
        is_connected = False
        print("My error is :",e.args)
        self.client.disconnect()


    finally:
        if is_connected:
            return True

def __getstate__(self):
    state = self.__dict__.copy()
    # Remove the unpicklable entries.
    del state['mylock']
    return state

# def __setstate__(self, state):
#     # Restore instance attributes.
#     self.__dict__.update(state)


# Declear property of a module
@property
def PLC(self):
    return self.plc
```

## Read connection settings from excel

def read_clienturl():

```
    data = df.iloc[2, 11]
    print(data)
    return data
```

def get_station_plc_name():

```
station_name = df.iloc[0, 11]
plc_name = df.iloc[1, 11]
return station_name,plc_name
```

## Main function call

if **name** == "**main**":
    comm = Communication()

```
print(f'plc name is : {comm.PLC}')
while True:
    comm.opc_client_connect()
    browser_id = '7:' + 'AR SOV OPN LS'
    var = comm.PLC.get_child("7:AR SOV OPN LS")
    value = var.get_value()
    print("value is : ", value)
    comm.client.disconnect()
```

when I try to use this code I got an error:-

File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 96, in _run
    self._receive()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 114, in _receive
    self._call_callback(0, ua.UaStatusCodeError(msg.Error.value))
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 124, in _call_callback
    .format(request_id, self._callbackmap.keys())
opcua.ua.uaerrors._base.UaError: No future object found for request: 0, callbacks in list are dict_keys([2])
My error is : ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/my files/python files/SMSPLCSIMULATIONV2-master (1)/SMSPLCSIMULATIONV2-master/clientcomm_v1.py", line 28, in opc_client_connect
    self.client.connect()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 259, in connect
    self.create_session()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 360, in create_session
    response = self.uaclient.create_session(params)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 267, in create_session
    data = self._uasocket.send_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 78, in send_request
    data = future.result(self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 434, in result
    raise TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 271, in disconnect
    self.close_session()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 476, in close_session
    return self.uaclient.close_session(True)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 291, in close_session
    data = self._uasocket.send_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 76, in send_request
    future = self._send_request(request, callback, timeout, message_type)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 67, in _send_request
    self._socket.write(msg)
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\common\utils.py", line 118, in write
    self.socket.sendall(data)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/my files/python files/SMSPLCSIMULATIONV2-master (1)/SMSPLCSIMULATIONV2-master/clientcomm_v1.py", line 92, in 
    comm.opc_client_connect()
  File "C:/my files/python files/SMSPLCSIMULATIONV2-master (1)/SMSPLCSIMULATIONV2-master/clientcomm_v1.py", line 45, in opc_client_connect
    self.client.disconnect()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 274, in disconnect
    self.disconnect_socket()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\client.py", line 283, in disconnect_socket
    self.uaclient.disconnect_socket()
  File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 248, in disconnect_socket

```
return self._uasocket.disconnect_socket()
```

File "C:\Users\chma02\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\opcua\client\ua_client.py", line 154, in disconnect_socket
    self._socket.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the exception. It states that the connection timed out. So to fix it I would first check if you can connect to the server with UA Expert. If it works with UA Expert maybe your firewall blocks the connection.